# Terraform create a kubernetes resource by using kubectl kustomization

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

In a manual way I can run this command to apply kustomized files in my cluster:

```
"kubectl kustomize my_deploy_templates/ | kubectl apply -f -"
```

How can I archive the same command above by using terraform hashicorp/kubernetes provider?
I know there is kbst/kustomization provider but it is not a possibility since it needs a kube config / raw file and it is not a way with my Microsoft aks.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I found an alternative way by using kustomization provider at the end (which is the offical way to deploy using Operator, suggested by AWXteam). As far as I understood hashcop/kubernetes provider cannot deal with kustomized parsed templates since it does not recognize custom kind:

│ Error: Failed to determine GroupVersionResource for manifest
│
│   with kubernetes_manifest.deploy_awx_client,
│   on main.tf line 35, in resource "kubernetes_manifest" "deploy_awx_client":
│   35: resource "kubernetes_manifest" "deploy_awx_client" {
│
│ no matches for kind "AWX" in group "awx.ansible.com"